# Is there a known mutation of an insertion type that prevents being infected by a virus?

Tags: virology, mutations, gene

Recently there was big news about the mutation CCR5 delta 32, that prevents HIV from infecting white blood cells, that was a deletion type of a mutation.

Do we know of an insertion type of mutation that have similar affect? i.e prevents being infected by specific/some virus(s)

Comment: Not an insertion but a gain-of-function mutation which causes virus resistance: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16306606 Are you looking for human examples or mutations in any organism?

Comment: I am happy with any organism